# Permanent connection to Database?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am currently working on a web-app, where I need to save some data on my MYSQL db.
The Db and the web server are installed on different hosts.

I am working with Java Servlets, JSP and MYSQL.

My question is: Should there be a permanent connection established at start and saved into the Server-context or should there be a temporary one for every single query?

Comment: Usually you'd use a connection pool that holds a (configurable) number of connections more or less indefinitely.

Comment: If you do end up doing it without connection pooling, use one connection per servlet request not per query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to use a connection pool.

The connection pool keeps a usually small number of open connections (connected to the DB) and provide an abstraction for your application.

This way, your application will avoid the overhead of finding the server, establishing the connection, closing the connection, etc on every query, which would sacrifice performance.

At the same time, a connection pool can avoid the situation that too many connections try to use the same database.

Usually, these connections live as long as the container is up, since it's up to the container manage this pool.

This [link](https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.htmlhttps://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) describes how Tomcat uses the commons-dbcp library to provide a JDBC connection pool.